# How can I delete a file/folder from Dropbox using the java api?

Tags: java, dropbox-api

I'm working on a project that leverages the backend Dropbox api's.  When I started, there was no java api, only an android api.  I used that and it had a function to delete and worked fine.  They recently came out with a more generic java version of the sdk that I'm almost switched over to, however, I can't seem to find in the documentation how to delete.

I realize that all of the sdk's sit on top of a rest api, but I would like to use the sdk to do everything, rather than use the rest api.

If anyone can help with how to delete from the java api, that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just downloaded the Dropbox Java SDK 1.6 and found this in the changelog:

> ---
>
> 1.6 (2013-07-07)
>
> - Completely rewritten SDK, focused on Java web apps.
> - Many API calls not yet implemented.
> - Not backwards compatible with previous versions.

Also looking at the JavaDoc did not reveal any remove/delete method ([Dropbox Java SDK JavaDoc](http://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-java/api-docs/v1.6.x/)). So I guess it is really not implemented yet. Either you do it yourself with REST or wait a little longer :)

Comment: I was afraid of that.  A lot of the doc is still missing explanations or have misspellings so looks like it's really new haha.  Oh well, guess I'll be waiting, not terribly needed now.  Thanks!

Comment: I hope they revise it soon ;)